# What is a matrix that has both a square root and a cube root?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I'm looking for the matrices $A$, $B$, $X$ such that $A^2 = B^3 = X$. Are there such matrices, and if so, how do I find them?

Comment: Um, A=C^3,B=C^2, X=C^6 for any matrix C?

Comment: For example, $X = I$ has every kind of root that you might want.

Comment: It turns out that every invertible matrix has some matrix with as a square/cube root.  Every real invertible matrix has a real cube root. Some nilpotent matrices have no square/cube root at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For any $n \in \mathbb{N}$, Let $Y$ be an $n\times n$ matrix.

Let $A = Y^3$ and $B  = Y^2$ and $X = Y^6$. Then $$ A^2 = B^3 = X = Y^6$$